# How set QuoteName settings in Json.Net?

Tags: json, json.net, settings

First of all, I know that it's not valid JSON format, but it's my customer web service settings, I need to set QuoteName of Json.Net JsonTextWriter to be false, but I don't know how to do it properly. This is my try:

```
foreach (var c in a)
  {
    var jsonobjects = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, new JsonTextWriter
       {
           QuoteName = false
        }
      );
    //Some code that using serialized json object
   }
```

In order to clarify what I want. I need to have Json property name without quotes. Something like that: {Property: "Value"}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

**The class:**

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public uint Number { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Serialization logic:**

```
var address = new Address
    {
        Street = "Fulton Street",
        Number = 100,
        City = "New York",
        ZipCode = "10038",
        State = "NY",
        Country = "USA"
    };

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
     writer.QuoteName = false;
     serializer.Serialize(writer, address);
}

var json = stringWriter.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    Street: "Fulton Street",
    Number: 100,
    City: "New York",
    ZipCode: "10038",
    State: "NY",
    Country: "USA"
}
```

**Example:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zazT1T